# Update package for Sublime Text 2

Tags: plugins, package, sublimetext2

I have authored a package ([LoremIpsum](https://github.com/billymoon/LoremIpsum)) for sublime text 2, and submitted it to the package control list. It has been working fine, and I can see 10K+ people installed the package (on the [community packages list](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community)). I have now updated it, and don't know how to inform the package control list.

Originally, I forked the package control list, added my package, and sent a pull request. I can not do that now, as I have no changes to make to the list - I just need to inform it that my package has updated (or do I? Does this happen automatically somehow?)

What should I do to make my updated version of the package available? How can I check that the correct version is published - and accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. Package Control will grab the latest from your repository. Though if you added a custom packages.json file you will need to update that also.

Also, on the community packages list you can look at the version date (at v2013.01.20.07.51.55 at the time of writing this). When it "updates", the version number will be updated.

Edit: 
Side note, you should add *.pyc to your .gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the info... when does it update? Is it on a timer - like every 24 hours or something?

Comment: So did it just take some time? I've got an update that I just pushed 10 minutes ago. Any further details would be great.

Comment: (Offtop) Please, see [**issue**](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight/issues/21) about PersistentRegexHighlight, when you will have a free time. Thanks.